# Laravel is returning objects with key:value instead of array of objects

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to return Json response as an array of objects. But instead I got response as object of objects. I have condition_question table where I save question_id and condition_id. I want to retrieve all questions which contains particular condition id. And sort them by answers_number. I am new to Laravel, here is my code:

```
 $conditionsIdArray = array($chosenConditionsIds);

        $results = Question::whereIn('question_id', function ($query) use ($conditionsIdArray) {
            $query->select('question_id')
                ->from('condition_question')
                ->whereIn('condition_id', $conditionsIdArray);
        })->get()->sortByDesc('answers_number')->take(5);

         return response()->json([
            'questions' => $results
        ], 200);
```

I get response:

```
{
    "questions": {
        "0": {
            "question_id": 842,
            "question_title": "Qui tempora...",
            "question_body": "Repellendus non sint...",
            "image": "https://lorempixel.com/640/480/?18901",
            "question_view_count": 17,
            "votes_number": 9,
            "answers_number": 9,
            "id_user": 9930,
            "created_at": "2019-09-07 09:59:05",
            "updated_at": "2019-09-08 18:23:41"
        },
        "28": {
            "question_id": 20346,
            "question_title": "Quaerat facere...",
            "question_body": "Repudiandae culpa ...",
            "image": "https://lorempixel.com/640/480/?91963",
            "question_view_count": 2,
            "votes_number": 2,
            "answers_number": 9,
            "id_user": 3546,
            "created_at": "2019-09-07 10:07:38",
            "updated_at": "2019-09-07 10:07:38"
        },etc
}
```

As you can see, I get object with object. I do not want key/value, just simple array of objects type Question.
I am struggling two days now, have tried some different stuff like toArray() but do not know how to solve it. Any help would be most welcome.

Comment: try to edit it to `response()->json($results, 200)`

Comment: Why do you return as json? just ```return $results```

Comment: Still not working as wanted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you change the keys in an indexed array, it will believe it has an associate array, due to sorting the index is off. On the `Laravel` collection there is a `values()` [method](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-values), which you can call there that reindex the collection.

```
return response()->json([
    'questions' => $results->values()
], 200);
```

Comment: Hi mrhn! It works, thank you! I was so close. I tried values(), but doing it in wrong way :) Thank for the link, will sure read more about it!

Comment: If it solved it, remember to accept the answer :) it is one of the quirky part of php arrays and the collection method basicly just call array_values() on the underlying array

Comment: For sure, I have to wait 3min to accept the answer :D By the way, is it possible to use $result->values() and return it as QuestionResource($result->values())?

Comment: you are dealing with a collection so you have to do QuestionResource::collection($result->values()).

values() only reindexed the array and keeps it a collection so should work.

Comment: Awesome, it works perfect! Now, my Angular ngFor knows to loop :D